# Incrementing address counter, ST7735 display driver

Tags: hardware, lcd

I'm programming a 1.8 display, with the ST7735R display driver. When you write pixel  data, you first set the frame, issue a RAMWR cmd, and then write all the pixeldata(according to the color mode 12-, 16- or 18-bit). Whenever you write pixel data, you increment the adress counter which tells which pixel in ram to write to next. This is my understanding of the driver, and it seems to work that way when i program it.

My question is. Can you in some way increment the adress counter without drawing pixel data? And without resizeing the frame of course(i don't wont to resize the frame more then once for every sprite).

Here is the datasheet:
http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/ST7735R_V0.2.pdf

Information about adress counter is on page  61.

Comment: You can set the "memory window" anywhere at any time. Take a look at my project on github which draws 16x16 tiles with a single set-col/set-row and then 256 pixels written sequentially. https://github.com/bitbank2/SPI_LCD